# Aggregation Repetition vs Nested Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query as the following:

```
SELECT SUM(`weight`) as totalgrams,
       SUM(`weight`)/1000 as totalkilograms
FROM `item`
```

which requires me to use the result of the first column's `SUM`, but since I can't use `totalgrams`, I need to redo `SUM` function again in the second column calculation. 
The query plan from `EXPLAIN`:
[image]

Now, with the second query:

```
SELECT totalgrams, totalgrams/1000 as totalkilograms
FROM (SELECT SUM(`weight`) as totalgrams
       FROM `item`) prequery
```

I don't need to repeat the `SUM` but I ended up with a nested query.
The query plan from `EXPLAIN`:
[image]

At a glance, it seems better to go with the first query, as it only has one entry in the execution plan, but was `SUM` calculated twice here (which is redundant and not scalable)?
Or actually the system already have an optimization for this and just calculate it once; so indeed the first query is better?

Right now there are only a few rows inside the table, so perhaps the difference is not significant in the real [ms] unit.
But if later it becomes huge, I wonder actually which query would be better?
And does it apply for all DBMS?

It is purely for understanding the SQL workflow, any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL materializes subqueries in the `from` clause -- the so-called derived table.  In this case, the summary has one row and one column, so it is really no big deal.

Including the `sum()` twice in the `select` does not have this overhead.  It is unclear from the explain output whether `sum()` is calculated once or twice.  Probably twice, but there could be an optimization step that eliminates that processing.  In any case, `sum()` is a really cheap.  The expensive part is arranging the aggregation, and all the aggregation functions are processed together.

Comment: ↑1 - "probably twice", this is what I want to make sure, Sir (perhaps someone had the same curiosity and already made sure of it). And perhaps, other than `sum()`, do all aggregation functions cheap as well? if not, then it seems that I would need to avoid this aggregation repetition.

Comment: @YohanesKhosiawan许先汉 . . . You really don't need to worry about repeating aggregation functions.  The process of doing *any* aggregation is rather expensive (generally a file sort in MySQL).  Once you do one, though, the second only does all the work once, and a very small incremental amount for the actual calculation.

Comment: I see, so does that mean aggregation repetition is better than the nested query? - I need to conclude -

Comment: I would go with the first solution, but the two would probably have very similar performance.

Answer (score 1):

You say this is purely for understanding the workflow, so I'll start my answer by saying mySQL does have means for optimizing these sort of operations and will do so but it isn't perfect and you shouldn't depend on it.  [PICKY] The example is not the best as a sum operation is trivial anyhow[/PICKY]

I would say your first solution is the better, but even better still would be to remove the need for the calculation at all.  Most of the time when a calculated column is used, it's simpler to code the calculation in the application that's getting the result, ie if this is called from php let php calculate total kilos instead of mysql.  It's a one time calculation based on a single return value and it doesn't matter whether mySQL optimizes it or not.  As I said earlier, sum is inexpensive, so for this particular example it isn't relevant but if the operation was something more expensive it would be a factor and for a general policy we should not assume the triviality of the operation.

If the outside language is an issue, another possibility would be to create an intermediate table and then update that table with the result.  In this case (a single row) the overhead makes this less desirable but if it were many rows in the result table (such as with a group by), or to create a general policy, the overhead becomes a non-issue.

Comment: ↑1 - thank you for the answer, but the scope is only within the db, and I want to know the comparison of the mentioned two queries. Thank you for the other alternative, though.